# Does 外公役 mean public servant?

Tags: translation, japanese-to-english

I am just translating the Japanese wikipedia chart of the servants in the Ooku of Edo Castle. I have been doing okay until I got to the omote-dzukai part. This is the original:

> 表使 (おもてづかい)    外公役。御年寄の指図で物資調達を広敷役人に要請していた。

I just need help with 外公役 as I am not too sure how I would translate that. Is it public servant or is it something like "role of outside relations"? It just does not sound right in this context (The sentence afterward being "Under the orders of the o-toshiyori, in charge of requesting the Hiroshiki official to procure supplies")

Comment: 「外**交**役」ならわかるんですが・・・「外**公**役」なんですよね・・

Comment: To the "close" voter -- the question is about the Japanese language, and about a specific term.  It is not helpful to vote to close because you think it's a typo, without at least commenting to clarify.  FWIW, [a Google search specific to this context](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%A4%96%E5%85%AC%E5%BD%B9%22+%22%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%A5%22) finds enough non-duplicated hits to suggest that this might not be just a typo.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I'm not the close voter, but don't you think that Chocolate's comment is sufficiently clear that we can now close the question as a typo error? I would have voted to close by now were it not for your comment.

Comment: Wait, I am a bit more confused... So, it could be a typo? And if so, since people are voting to close this then is my question against the community rules?

Comment: The term that @Chocolate mentions is 外交役, from 外交 ("diplomacy") + 役 ("post, office").  The term in the question is a very specific term, a job title in Edo Castle during the Bakufu period.  I suspect that this is not a typo for 外交役, and is instead 外 ("outer, outside") + 公役 ("civil servant", synonym for 公務員).

Comment: @user3856370 I can only see that comment as merely suggestive, not assertive, of the phrase's typo status. Even if it was an assertion, I don't think any single person's claim, let alone an unsubstantiated one, should be automatically taken to constitute a truth. (That said, I tend to agree that it is a typo, after some research and consideration.)

Comment: @Eiríkr, 辞書に「公役 "civil servant"」はあるんですけど、「外 "outer, outside" + 公役 "civil servant"」って語になってるようなソースとか、何かないですかね？　「外公役」ってググっても、中国語のページか、Wiki の「大奥」のページと同じ文脈（引用かコピペ）か、「その[外]{ほか} 公役...」みたいな文脈しかないんですよね・・（「梶原平馬...若くして藩の外公役を任される」っていうページもあったけど、梶原平馬をググったら他は全部「外交」になってるし・・試しに「内公役」探しても日本語のページは「領内公役」とかだし・・）

Comment: @Zoe Absolutely nothing wrong with your question. No need to worry. It doesn't break any rules. Close votes aren't always a bad thing. This was just a discussion to make sure we don't go closing questions without thinking properly first.

Comment: @Chocolate, タイポである可能性は承知します。ただ、タイポである根拠など、理由を説明するコメントなしで「タイポだからクローズ」になる結末は避けたいです。昔の職名ですし、とても狭い分野ですので、聞かれたらせめて少しでも調査したほうが良いかと思います。「外公役」をそのWP記事に追加されたのは、2007年1月2日に[このエディット](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%A5&diff=9801206&oldid=9710751)で、追加したユーザは Shelling ford 221b でした。